# Sending a binary message with RabbitQM SimpleAmqpClient

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm writing in C++ and want to send binary data (Serialized Google Protobufs) using the SimpleAmqpClient library. The only message type I see is BasicMessage. The only way to populate a BasicMessage seems to be with an std::string. Is publishing a BasicMessage with an std::string holding binary data (GProtobufs serialize themselves this way) going to work?

Comment: Not a user of RabbitQM, all I can say is that a `std::string` is able to hold any character sequence, including ones with embedded nulls and non-printable characters.  It is the `size()` that determines the length of the string, not a null-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

So I got around to trying this. Initializing a BasicMessage from a string with binary data including nulls does work as I had hoped. I would feel better if I knew this was an intentionally supported feature and part of the SimpleAmqpClient test suite.

I previously posted that it worked; then posted that it didn't. Well it actually does.